# how to send data in this formate i had this model i want in this formate

Tags: node.js, reactjs

```js
  board12th :{
        type : String,
    },
    rollNo12th :{
        type : String,
    },
    subjectDetails12th :[{
        subject1 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject2 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject3 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject4 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject5 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String}
    }],
    totalMarks12th :{
        type : String,
    },
```

i want to send data in this formate i had all the values

```
 board12th :{
        type : String,
    },
    rollNo12th :{
        type : String,
    },
    subjectDetails12th :[{
        subject1 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject2 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject3 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject4 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String},
        subject5 :{ type : String},
        marks :{type : String}
    }],
    totalMarks12th :{
        type : String,
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const payload = {
  board12th : 'board12th value',
    rollNo12th : '12',
    subjectDetails12th :[{
        subject1 :'science',
        marks : '74',
        subject2 :'account',
        marks :'67,
        subject3 :'statatistics',
        marks :'78',
        subject4 :'computer',
        marks : '85',
        subject5 : 'ss',
        marks :'55'
    }],
    totalMarks12th : '251'
}
```

you can pass this payload const into api payload